# How to get an updating value of an input field without using DOM or useState inside an array map

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
disCoins.map((c) => {
            
                let subTotal;

            function calcSubTotal(subAmount){
                subTotal = (Number(c.current_price) * Number(subAmount));
                console.log(subAmount);
                return subTotal;
            }

            return(
                <div id="calcElement">
                <img id="coinImg" src={c.image} alt="Coin img"></img>
                <div id="calcInfo">
                    <div id="calcName">{c.name}<span id="calcSymbol">  ({capitalize(c.symbol)})</span></div>
                    <div id="calcPrice">
                        ${formatNumber(c.current_price)}
                        <span id="calcChange" className={c.price_change_percentage_24h < 0 ? "loss" : "gain"}>  ({c.price_change_percentage_24h}%)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="x">
                    <span>×</span>
                </div>
                <div id="amountInput">
                    <form>
                        <input id="amountInputField" type="number" placeholder="Amount of Crypto Owned" defaultValue='0'  onChange={calcSubTotal(Number(3))}></input>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="eq">
                    <span>=</span>
                </div>
                <div id="subTot">
                    <span id="subTotal">${formatNumber(subTotal)}</span>
                </div>
                </div>
            )})
```

How would I be able to get the value of that input field and have it change when it updates? React doesn't let me use useState and DOM gives me an error when I add the first item into the list because it reads the value as null.

Comment: You probably want to make it into a separate component

Comment: I agree. Mapping directly into a sub-component, passing ```c``` as ```props``` and having each individual component keep state for the ```subtotal``` variable is probably best.

Comment: The problem is, items of the disCoin array are not all there from initialization. They are added on by the user post render of the website, so I’m not sure how I’d be able to have a state for each potential item added